# Refresh JFrame from Jinternal Frame

Tags: java, swing, refresh

Hello Friends I have a swing application that has extends JFrame and has JInternalFrames. I need to Refresh the MainFrame from an ActionEvent in JInternalFrame.
My MainFrame(Pseudo)

```
    public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    .................

    }
public void Refresh(){
    invalidate();
    validate();
    }
```

My JInternalFrame(Pseud0)

```
public class EndOfTerm extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

.........
new MainFrame().Refresh();

}

}
```

I am getting two frames after the ActionEvent, One without Components and the second one with Components that seem to Overlap. Please Help. #Beginner#

Comment: `new MainFrame().Refresh();` by this you are creating new instance of mainframe instead you should refer to same instance that initiated internal frame. For more help post SSCCE.

Comment: please don't take as ..., just my curiosity because I don't know any real reason (code isn't in SSCCE form), can you describe your reason,

Comment: My Classes are very huge as it is a Big Application.

Comment: don't extend JFrame, use Object declared as local variable, othewise to use methods from SwingUtilities, e.g. [Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(Component c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent%28java.awt.Component%29) then variable window is the same as local variable for JFrame (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save your MainFrame in your InternalFrame.

```
public class EndOfTerm extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener{

    private MainFram mainFrame;

    public EndOfTerm(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        .........
        mainFrame.Refresh();

    }

}
```

When you create your InternalFrame you have to pass your MainFrame.

```
new InternalFrame(this);
```

Comment: Where did you get the NullPoinerException?

Comment: Its coming on the Main Frame

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which method throws the Exception and which line. Post some more source code please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also call getParent(this) inside of your JInternalFrame to get a reference to the enclosing JFrame.